# Elastic Search: "fuzzy_like_this_field" not working properly

Tags: java, elasticsearch, full-text-search, spring-data-elasticsearch

### ES Query

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "fuzzy_like_this_field": {
          "Product.productInfo": {
            "like_text": "code=9787 Cornichons, qty=1.0, amt=0.89,code=37424 Pasta Spez. frisch, amt=1.29, totalCost=0.0, vat=0.0",
            "fuzziness": 0.5
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "must_not": [],
    "should": []
  }
}
```

I want result which matches with `code=9787` and  `amt=0.89`, `totalCost=100.0`, `vat=2.0`.

However, it returns all results which contain `code=` or `amt=` or `qty=`. It not checks  `code`'s, `amt`'s, `qty`'s values.

Comment: Why down-voted this question?

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy, in elasticsearch, only handles similar *text*.  E.g. "Cornichons" ~= "Cornicons".

If you want to enable ranges (near to your "like" document), for say the numeric values of (cost, vat, amt, etc...), then add those range queries directly instead  of fuzzy search.

Comment: Hey Peter..as per elastic documents fuzzy_like_this_field handles exact similar and  near to similar text according to fuzziness value                                 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-flt-field-query.html  and I want those records which are exact similar or near to similar

Comment: Correct.  Similarity is defined by Levenshtein Distance (or the number of **character** replacements required to produce an identical string).  It does not know how to identify numeric values in close proximity (small delta).  Only text.

Comment: You have any idea/suggestion ?

Comment: Parse your text string into the appropriately-typed fields which you care about.  Index it.  Use range queries to define the variances in amt, totalCost and vat you'll accept.